# Read-only FS how to resize with unionfs-fuse

Tags: fstab

I am running several raspberries as read-only system for about 2 years.. so save them from corrupt sdcards i run them read-only. So far this has proven working very well.

This is how my df looks like;

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        7541056  994664   6210252  14% /
devtmpfs          218256       0    218256   0% /dev
tmpfs             222544       0    222544   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs             222544    4608    217936   3% /run
tmpfs               5120       4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs             222544       0    222544   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs             222544    1580    220964   1% /tmp
unionfs-fuse     7763600 7542636    220964  98% /var
unionfs-fuse     7763600 7542636    220964  98% /home
/dev/mmcblk0p1     64456   21304     43152  34% /boot
```

As you can see /var is rather full.. and this sometimes leads to problems. This is how my /etc/fstab looks like;

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults                0       0
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot           vfat    defaults,ro             0       2
/dev/mmcblk0p2  /               ext4    defaults,noatime,ro     0       1
tmpfs           /tmp            tmpfs   mode=1777,nosuid,nodev 0 0
tmpfs /var/lib/lightdm tmpfs defaults,noatime,nosuid,size=100m 0 0
unionfs-fuse#/tmp=rw:/ro/home=ro  /home  fuse   cow,allow_other
unionfs-fuse#/tmp=rw:/ro/var=ro  /var  fuse   cow,allow_other,nonempty
```

I tried increasing the size=100m but this doesn't seem to change anything on the /var side. Any ideas how I can increase /var?

Comment: It's only cosmetical (unless an application would check for statfs/statvfs output), but not difficult to fix in unionfs-fuse.

Comment: Yes well I do have some applications (for example apt-get) that reports the filesystem being full.. but how to enlarge it?